# Zomato api with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zomato-api

I'm fairly new to coding and am having issues loading data from the Zomato API with angulars $http. I keep getting invalid API key popping up as an error in my console even though im using the API key generated by Zomato.

Here is a snippet of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/3j1c816v/1/

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?',
    params: {
        user_id: '', // API key
        entity_type: 'city', 
        q: 'food',
    }
```

Please let me know if i'm doing anything wrong or any helpful resources i can use to fix my issue!

Thank you

Comment: from the zomato documentation,  for the api key you need to use user_key not user_id. try changing that.

Comment: changed it and i still get the same error in the console..

Answer (score 1):

`user_key` is not a GET parameter but a **header** parameter.

You should try this:

```js
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?',
    headers: {'user_key' : 'api_key_goes_here'},
    params: {
        entity_type: 'city', 
        q: 'food',
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks i'm pretty sure you're right, however chrome is sending an OPTIONS request and Zomato's api doesn't  respond to OPTIONS requests so its breaking :( might switch to different api

Comment: That's probably related to CORS, not allowing localhost to consume their API.

Answer (score -1):

I Think zomato have ended their API service & No longer the API is running.

But I have made an unofficial Zomato API at here : https://github.com/ripyas/zomato-api

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33316385)